Concatenate while using Choice column in SharePoint
I have 3 columns (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) that need to concatenate in ColumnD. Final product should look like : ColumnA-ColumnB-ColumnC
ColumnC is a multiple selection Choice column so I cannot make ColumnD a calculated column type for concatenation
I created a workflow to account for choice columns. So if ColumnA is "Building" and ColumnB is "Room" and if ColumnC has multiple values like "202" and "105" and "306," ColumnD output appears like this: Building-Room-202;105;306
But I need ColumnD data to appear like this...
Building-Room-202
Building-Room-105
Building-Room-306
How can I achieve this?
Note:
1 - I am using SharePoint 2010 Workflows; cannot use anything else.
2 - I DO NOT have PowerApps
3 - SharePoint List 2013
4 - ColumnD is "Multiple lines of text"
5 - Here is the standard step1 I am using:
Set Variable:105 to [%Current Item:ColumnA%]-[%Current Item:ColumnB%]-105
If Current Item:ColumnC contains 105
Update Item in Current Item
Field: ColumnD
Value: Variable:105
